# Is there an adhesive that could used for larval fish?

Tags: biochemistry, zoology, ichthyology, experimental-design

I am currently working on an experimental design that requires a larval fish (~ 4mm long) to be affixed on a metal wire tip on its dorsal side. Now, I was thinking of a glue or adhesive to do the job, but it doesn't have to be strictly these, anything that sufficiently attaches the fish to the metal wire tip would do. The glue/adhesive would have to work well on wet surface and, ideally, something that is not toxic. Any advice or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try methyl cellulose, which my lab and others use. It's not exactly an adhesive, but it is quite viscous. It's common enough that it's in the Zebrafish Book: https://wiki.zfin.org/display/prot/Methyl+Cellulose+Mounting . Obviously, be sure whatever you do is approved by your animal care and use committee.